# A word... for determination? Or stubbornness

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the word that means: someone told you that you'd fail, so you did it.

Like... someone says you'd be a horrible father, and you become one and become the best father ever. Someone tells you that that they would never imagine you as a tattoo artist, and you become one and become very successful.

Like, being determined to do something and succeed, only because someone said you wouldn't succeed in it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a phrase that is commonly used like an adjective which has that meaning:

> She had an *I'll-show-them* attitude.

You could also say that this attitude is a kind of *defiance*.